# Doesn't any massive conductor look like "ground" to an AC supply?

Tags: electricity, everyday-life, electric-current, potential, voltage

I've been puzzling over [this excellent answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/80685/41836) to the perennial "*Why don't I get shocked by a hot wire if I'm not grounded?*" question.  The orders of magnitude just don't seem right for two reasons:

1. The answer claims that the *surface area* of the "capacitive body" is the relevant metric.  If the body is full of conductive mass is it not the *volume* that applies?
2. Household electric service is often grounded by a "ground rod" – literally a long conductor driven into the earth.  The earth it contacts is not necessarily a good conductor, so I don't understand how a ground rod can dissipate many orders of magnitude more current than can, say, a person of the same height and conductive volume.

So let's look at the simple case of an adult grabbing the hot wire of a 120V, 60Hz AC household electric supply:  I just measured the resistance of my skin and found it to be in the hundreds of kΩ.  Let's call it 120 kΩ to make the math easy: if the RMS voltage is 120V then I can conduct 1mA of current – assuming that I have ground potential.

I touch the ground, and sure enough, no charge is transferred.  I have the same electric potential as the ground.  So I grab that hot wire and the question is: **When do I start looking to the electric supply like I'm *not* the ground?**

Because once that supply gets through my insulating skin I'm electrically equivalent to a 20-gallon vat of highly-conductive saline.  I start at ground potential, and my body will take current until it matches the potential of the power supply.  But this is AC power, so I only "charge" for 1/120s before the polarity changes and I'm giving up electrons where before I was receiving them.

**At 1mA, does 20 gallons of saline acquire a significant charge in 1/120s?**  If not, then it shouldn't matter whether some part of my body is touching a ground or not: the shock should be the same, because my body is "as good as ground" until it is brought significantly closer to the same potential as the power supply.

Furthermore, to question #1 above, assuming that saline is in an insulated container, does it matter what shape the container is?  I just can't see how that could make a difference as far as the current is concerned.

Comment: I've deleted an extended comment discussion. Please remember that comments are not for discussions, they're for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification, and sometimes for pointing out related resources.

Answer (score 1):

One main point you're missing I think is that the voltage *doesn't* get through your insulating skin. You have a sharp voltage drop across your skin, through which very little current flows due to the high impedance, and your highly-conductive insides are more-or-less shielded.

Another point is that the total amount of charge the circuit will give you is dependent on your capacitance. If we make the blithe assumption that you are a uniform conducting sphere of $\sim1\rm{m}$ in radius, your capacitance is $C=4\pi\epsilon_0(1\rm{m})$. The charge you can collect is given by $Q=CV\approx 10\rm{nC}$. So the average current at the very least cannot be greater than $10\rm{nA}$. (The peak current depends on the amount of resistance- lower resistance means higher peak current, as you would expect).

The earth on the other hand has effectively infinite capacitance, and so it is not limited in this regard. So if you are electrically connected to the earth, it's only the resistance of your body that is saving you. In ideal conditions, this is still usually not a lethal shock, but with something like wet skin it can be.

As far as the shape of the saline container, it can matter a lot. The charge buildup that keeps more than $10\rm{nC}$ from building up builds up around the surface of the volume (as conductors cannot build up charge inside). So if the container were instead a 20 gallon kiddie pool or something, the charge would be able to spread out a lot more, and the pool would be more capable of accepting charge (in physics terms, it would have a larger capacitance).

Comment: I understand that the "ground" is the reference charge, and in theory the earth has vast capacitance.  But at 120V I don't understand how standard earth can absorb that much current.  Typical soil resistivity is on the order of 1kΩ per meter.  So 120V just isn't going to push kilojoules into the ground!  Then you bring the "surface" charge into the equation.  Where does the conductive surface end with respect to the ground rod?  If we accidentally drove the ground rod into a plot surrounded by a 6' HDPE pipe (insulator) would it also have negligible capacitance?

Comment: Also, what is the thing I have supposedly proposed to try that everyone is warning me not to try?

Comment: The *resistivity* is very large, but the surface area of the poles driven into the earth is also very large. So the resistance is not large. Intuitively you can think of it as many large resistances in parallel giving one small resistance.

Comment: I believe it's the fact you said "So I grab that hot wire" (presumably hypothetically) that people think you might actually have tried grabbing the hot wire.

Comment: Hmm ... the proposal was "grab the hot wire" and then, if my understanding is correct, get ready for your body to charge as fast as it can (part of the question was how just how fast that can happen at a given current) up to 120V and back 120 times per second.  The Darwin awards were made for people who think that sounds like a good idea and stop reading the actual question to try it themselves.  But I'm still baffled at all the warnings *this* question garnered given that the site is littered with questions involving high-voltage lines, lasers, particle beams, guns, vacuums, explosives, etc.

Comment: I have grabbed the hot wire, by accident, when rewiring some lighting fixtures. I don't recall all the details, but I had disconnected the lighting circuit, which killed the lights, and opened the switch box. The wiring was not code compliant: the neutral was still hot, as it had been borrowed. I was shocked see such unsafe work. Since then I always check with a meter even when I think the circuit is off.

Comment: @Chris : Why do you say "The earth on the other hand has effectively infinite capacitance"? The earth capacitance is just 0.7 mF (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance#Self-capacitance), that is not so much.

Answer (score 0):

A closed conducting volume, such as a metal sphere, collects charge from a source until the net charge on the surface of the sphere is sufficient to match the driving EMF.  That is, as the sphere accumulates charge, there is a voltage generated which will increase, approach, and finally be equal to that of the driving EMF.

At this point the sphere can no longer accept any further charge from that source, because the voltages are equal.

OTOH, a good ground never "fills up" because it is connected to a vast reservoir with a lower electric field, and hence a lower voltage.  If your putative ground is able to accumulate charge, then it is not a "true ground".  Consult your local building code for the local requirements.  In many jurisdictions it is sufficient to drive a metal rod into the ground below the freeze line, because the local ground is always damp.  In other locations, especially very dry ones, one must go deeper.

But a bad ground not only leads to trouble with your electronics, but can be hazardous to your well being.  The key is that a current always flows from higher to lower potential, just as water always flows downhill.

Comment: But the ground resistivity and supply voltage have something to do with the ground, right?  At a high enough voltage, my body or "insulated saline vat" *is* a ground because the voltage will push current past my insulating footwear into the ground, or ionize the air and find a path to other nearby masses with a greater charge differential.  OTOH, at low voltage a ground system that's good for 120V won't be able to dissipate a high current as fast, and so it actually could "fill up" and behave just like the insulated vat, right?

Comment: A properly implementation for a grounding system takes into account factors like the maximum current and votage expected. Your residential building code is designed to address common situations.  For complex industrial situations significant engineering may be required.

Comment: Current will flow toward from higher to lower potential, and all paths will be used ... but when you solve the circuit you will find that the path of least resistance carries the highest current. Just apply Kirchoff's rules and Ohm's law and you will be off to a good start. Every community college offers courses, and you can build some stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Displacement current makes not much sense around 120v ranges. I assume there will be only very small of it will exist even if exist at all at this voltage level.

You must understand that the ground current flows from your household wiring into earth because the neutral wire has been grounded at the utility sub station. This grounding is what actually differentiate the neutral from the live on the otherwise non polar alternating current power source.

Having said that, the ground current flows because there is the closed loop through the earth although its not perfectly conductive.

Now, no matter how volumetric or huge your body is, as long as it is not properly coupled (resistively or capacitively) to the ground, the current which may flow into ground to return back to its neutral grounding at the substation will be extremely small and possibly out of the sensitivity of your body or any standard measuring equipment.

Comment: So AC current flow ultimately *does* require a truly close loop?  I.e., if we constructed an infinite insulating panel to divide the earth between the service ground rod and the utility ground then touching the supply conductor to the service ground only negligible current would flow?

Comment: @feetwet No, not really. This answer is true in principle if there is no capacitive coupling between an object and ground (and indeed between you and the ground this is negligible), but service ground would have a massive capacitive coupling with utility ground and current would flow just about as easily.

Comment: Yes.... Only negligible current will flow.  Stray capacitance may help close the loop but its significance, I believe will be too small.

Comment: OK, if soosai is right then I can understand this in theory.  If @Chris is right then I am confused and could use more explanation of what he said: I am unfamiliar with the concept of capacitive coupling on such a large scale, and in the proposed theoretical isolation.

Comment: @feetwet Imagine the whole system with the two separated grounds as a simple RC circuit with some resistance and very, very large capacitance. Current flows equal to V/R initially and it slows down as the capacitor charges. If the capacitance is effectively infinite as it would be in this case, the capacitor never charges appreciably (particularly in 1/120 s), and so a constant current flows: it just looks like only the resistor is there.

Comment: @feetwet Reading about [complex impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance) might be helpful.

Comment: Put this argument in this scenario. Let say you have a mobile ac generator placed on well insulated platform. Of course there will be a very small capacitive coupling between the generator and the earth. Generator will have at least two output terminals. Let take only one of it and shove it into a very well established grounding point through a sensitive ac mili ammeter. Chris, can you pls tell us how the current read out will be against the timeline, say 0 to 5 second?

Comment: @soosaisteven In this case, the terminal presumably has a very, very small capacitance to ground, so the current would no doubt be very small.

Comment: Exactly Chris.... You are right, the metric of the capacitance is the determining factor, together with the voltage in the system. Thus, answering the original question, its absolutely safe for ungrounded person to touch live wire at 120V ac 60 Hz because human body capacitance to the ground is very small. The capacitive reactance the body will exhibit to the 120V ac at 60Hz will be simply too high for any significant current to flow.  It may be slightly dangerous if human body is like a flat pancake and floating parallel to the ground in which case the capacitive reactance might be very low.