# Why does a bird not get electrocuted when it is sitting on a high tension electric wire?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, everyday-life

Why does a bird not get electrocuted when it is sitting on a high tension electric wire?

Comment: Tip: Check the right margin for related questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do birds sitting on electric wires not get shocked?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41770/)

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

This is because the bird is not grounded. That is, there is no potential difference for electricity to flow (eg. It is not touching anything conductive that touches the ground - air doesn't count because its conductivity is very poor and hence negligible). But, as soon as the bird touches the pole, the bird fries because now, the electricity flow can occur from the high voltage/potential in the wire to the pole (metallic conductor), which is connected to the ground or at zero potential.

Answer (score 0):

The difference of potential between the bird and the wire is zero, so the electric current that can pass through the system is zero because the density of charge is zero.

$Δ^2V = - \frac{ϱ}{ε}$